# How can I use 3 group by in one query statement sql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[This is my query.Group by query in one table and I wanna get three sum column in select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMzN.png)

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9KuL.png)

[This is what I really want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHZX1.png)

Comment: As per question guidelines, please do not post any images. Please elaborate more on your problem and what you've tried

Comment: thank you I am newbie in stack over flow.Sorry .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE statement to achieve this result as shown below.

```
SELECT sales_id,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'deposit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS deposit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'withdrawn' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS withdrawn,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'commission' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS commission
FROM `ds_wd20_files` GROUP BY sales_id
```

Please replace sales_id with sales person name